# Help with finding this locus of points

Tags: functions, conic-sections, locus

Let $(a, b)$ be a fixed point, and $(x, y)$ a variable point, on the curve $y = f(x)$, $(x \geq a, f
′
(x) \geq 0).$
The curve divides the rectangle with vertices $(a, b),(a, y),(x, y)$ and ($x, b$) into two portions,
the lower of which has always half the area of the upper. Show that the curve is an arc of a
parabola with its vertex at $(a, b)$.

I have tried fixing ($a,b$) as ($0,0$) and finding the directrix and focus of the parabola but I can't seem to justify how the information about the area implies that f(x) is a parabola in the first place.

Comment: Please do not post unsearchable images of text.  Instead typeset.

Comment: Sorry I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 1):

Wlog $a=b=0$. Then, your constraint on areas reads $\int_0^xf=\frac13xf(x)$ so by differentiation $2f(x)=xf'(x)$, hence $f(x)= Cx^2$.

Comment: Thank you, this clears up my confusion.

Comment: You are welcome.The right way to thank for an answer is not by a comment but by marking the answer as accepted.